# Would a relatively large (~20MB) APK size prevent or discourage any users from installing the app?

Tags: android, apk

The title says most of it. I believe packaging the basic data set into the app will result in a better user experience, rather than have people download files before they can start using the app. This is where one can start losing users. At the same time, 20MB is considered kind of a lot for Android,so I wonder if this will cause issues for some users in using the app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will cause an issue. I am an android developer who uses android phone and facebook app in my fone is almost 21MB. It does not cause any issue...However, as a developer a better approach would be to do an app that does not exceed 10MB space(Unless your app is outstanding like Facebook). You can do this by using images of smaller size,making sure you do not have any resources that you are not using(classes,layouts etc)

Answer (score 0):

The size never causes issue but you may consider more:

I am a android developer and a long time Android user too. Not All Android phones have high-end processors to run app faster.

A lot of Android Phones have phone memory of 100-250MB. And the old versions of Android doesn't allow user to install app on SD card. So the user may hesitate to install your App.

Unless it is necessary try to reduce the App size.

Answer (score 0):

As per my personal experience, If you are designing something astonishing and it costs even few hundred MBs on my phone, so i really wouldn't mind to give a try. Since new phones, processors and high storage capacities are continuously evolving and appearing in consumers' hands, so how can we expect applications to remain the same (tiny) in size? Let them grow (but not without any valid reason), and people would still try/buy it. There are no fixed rules or guidelines for limiting the app size, but a directly proportional relationship explains it well:

`High-end graphics and feature-rich application` **∝** `Extra size/memory`

Answer (score 0):

What I think is :

The size of the app never creates issue. Again if its an extraordinary app. then surely user will surely get attracted and download your app..

But on the other side just think about the Internal Memory of the phone. There are lots of phone available that has very low internal memory(many have 150 or 180MB as internal memory). May be because of too low internal memory, they wont be able to use your application and hence you may not get big traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of answers here so I'm just going to give you my perspective.

1. I would be frustrated to say the least if I downloaded a 10MB app and then opened it to find I needed to download another 10MB of necessary materials. Just make the app 20MB so I know what I'm getting into when I start the download.
2. Only put the bear essentials into the app if it's going to be that big. Don't require users to download high res images, language packs, etc. Just publish the bare minimum that your app requires to run if it's going to be larger than 10MB. You could even publish two versions of your app, the bare minimum at 7MB or the HOLY SH*T package at 20MB, at least users would have a choice when they went to download your app.
3. Spend some time looking up common practices when it comes to saving space when making an app, every little bit counts and if you can make the same app and save 5MB, your users will appreciate it. If it comes down to a lot of images, consider using this tool; http://www.getpaint.net. However I would suggest reducing the JPEG quality) rather than compress them. JPEGs aren't very squishy.

Going along with #3. Think about universally accepted methods of communication; a sideways triangle for a play button, and X for a delete button, be sneaky...save space. User's love that crap :]